# Setting up Usernames and Passwords on Icecast Server 2

Tags: mysql, wordpress, digital-ocean, icecast, internet-radio

I have an Icecast Server 2 set up on Digital Ocean. I am using the "butt - broadcast using this tool" to broadcast to a mountpoint on the server by inputting my password and icecast username.

Now, I am trying to set up a sign up webpage that will need to interface with the icecast server config file, and add user names and passwords as people sign up.

**What is the best way to do this?**

1. Wordpress -> mySQL -> Icecast?
2. Webform -> Icecast?
3. ?

Also, can I host this on the same droplet as my icecast server?

Any sample code snippets, tutorials, links, documentation will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Icecast has a simple yet powerful URL authentication capability against arbitrary HTTP/HTTPS back ends. This can be used both for listener clients and for source clients. All that is needed is to parse the request sent and reply with a confirmation header.

For further details, refer to the [official documentation](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/auth.html#url) on this topic.

You can either run this on the same machine or somewhere else. This is up to you where you point the URL.